# Como passar um segundo parâmetro utilizando .htaccess para um código php?

Tags: php, json, linux, htaccess, url-amigável

Estou escrevendo a minha api utilizando urls amigáveis com .htaccess para fazer os redirecionamentos.

Na hora que preciso passar um segundo parâmetro, estou tendo problemas

Meu arquivo .htaccesss está assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^mesas\/?([0-9]+)\/?(.+)\/?$ mesas.php?status=$1
RewriteRule ^statusmesa\/?([0-9]+)\/?(.+)\/?$ statusmesa.php?idmesa=$1&status=$2
```

Quando utilizo a chamada para statusmesa usando `statusmesa/2/3`, ele retorna como primeiro parâmetro o `2` e como segundo `5.php/2/5`

O que está errado na minha regra?

Answer (score -1):

Se você apenas repetir a regra do primeiro parâmetro não funciona?

```
RewriteRule ^statusmesa\/?([0-9]+)\/?([0-9]+)\/?$ statusmesa.php?idmesa=$1&status=$2
```

**Exemplo**

Exemplo de url amigável: http://www.meudominio.com.br/artigos/26/12/2014

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)\/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)\/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)\/?$ exemplo1.php?dia=$1&mes=$2&ano=$3
```

> RewriteRule – Define o início de uma regra de reescrita;
>
> ([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+) – Todos os caracteres (Números e Letras) + _
>   -;
>
> / – Barras;
>
> /? – Uma barra ou vazio.

Neste [site](https://www.hostdime.com.br/ajuda/shell/urls-amigaveis-manipulando-urls-com-htaccess-e-mod_rewrite/) existem alguns exemplos e explicações mais detalhadas que podem te ajudar

Comment: Não funcionou. Teria algo a ver com a regra RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?

Comment: @Murilo Ai já não sei te dizer, nunca utilizei isso, quando eu fiz, utilizei o nome do arquivo direto.